# a perl regular expression for picking up IP addresses out of fwsm/asa firewall rules?

Tags: regex, perl, rt

I am using [rt] and would like to create an action to parse a series of firewall rules and pick up the IP addresses in them as a comma-separated value to be applied to a field.  My firewall rules look like this:

```
access-list ACL-outside-1net extended permit tcp host 172.16.0.7 host 10.0.1.55 eq www
access-list ACL-outside-1net extended permit tcp host 172.16.0.9 host 10.0.1.56 eq www
```

And it would be great if I could have a regex that will snarf whatever occurs after "host" and return them as a comma-separated string **without picking up everything until the end of the line**, which is my current point of failure.

i.e. my ideal output from the regex would be:

```
172.16.0.7,10.0.1.55,172.16.0.9,10.0.1.56
```

The rules I'm interested in will always end in `eq $service or $port` and the IP address will be preceded by `host`, but the IP address can be ipv4 or ipv6 and [rt] will be smart about parsing the address, so I would rather pick up "after host up to host" and "after host up to eq", but I'm having a hard time getting a regex to match, let alone replace into a comma-separated string.

lil' help?

### edit 201305080832

I've been asked (and appropriately downvoted) to share my work, so here is my template that I'm working in for [rt].

```
IPs|Body|host(.*)||
```

My custom field is named `IPs` and I'm doing a `Body` search for "host" and then have been doing a greedy match that isn't an acceptable IP address for the `Multi-value IP address` field in [rt].  The suggestions below may be workable if I change from using a template and `ExtractCustomFieldValue` to writing a scrip action specific for this use case.

---

`[rt]` Request Tracker

Comment: for reference, you should attempt to do the code yourself and post what you have.  Otherwise, most people will not want to answer your questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $s="access-list ACL-outside-1net extended permit tcp host 172.16.0.7 host 10.0.1.55 eq www";

if ($s =~ /host(.*) host(.*) eq.*/)
{
    print "$1\n$2\n";
}
```

Use parenthesis for grouping with extraction.  The elements from the first group go into `$1` and the elements from the second group go into `$2'.  .* will get all characters except for newline. Good luck.

Edit: To be more precise, you could use this:

```
if ($s =~ /host((?:[0-9]|.)+) host((?:[0-9]|.)+) eq.*/)
    {
        print "$1\n$2\n";
    }
```

(?:..) says to group, but not to extract. [0-9]|. says that you demand that all characters be 0-9 or .

To print out everything on one line, simply write a loop to go through all the lines and use commas instead of \n to separate them.

Comment: Demanding a numeric value like that will mean ipv6 addresses don't get picked up, but I think your first example is getting me closer and I'll continue to beat on it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following will be helpful:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Regexp::Common qw/net/;

my ( @IPs, @ips );
while (<DATA>) {
    push @IPs, @ips if @ips = /($RE{net}{IPv4})/g;
}

print join ',', @IPs;

__DATA__
access-list ACL-outside-1net extended permit tcp host 172.16.0.7 host 10.0.1.55 eq www
access-list ACL-outside-1net extended permit tcp host 172.16.0.9 host 10.0.1.56 eq www
```

Output:

```
172.16.0.7,10.0.1.55,172.16.0.9,10.0.1.56
```

This uses the module [Regexp::Common](http://search.cpan.org/~abigail/Regexp-Common-2013031301/lib/Regexp/Common/net.pm) to capture IPs on each line, and those are `push`ed onto `@IPs` and are later `print`ed after being `join`ed with a ','.